# Maya I want to store in an array

Tags: python, maya

Store the selection of keys that are selected in the image I made as an example. That selection information can be used later to reselect the keys.
I want to store in an array to be able to select them later by means of the index.

The script creates the animation keys. How can I select the new keys, either the key before or after the current frame in the timeline?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QLDp.gif)

```
import maya.cmds as mc

def insertKeyPercentage(percentage = 100):

key1 = mc.currentTime(q = True)

p = 4

key2 = mc.setKeyframe(i = True, t = (key1 +p))
key3 = mc.setKeyframe(i = True, t = (key1 -p))

insertKeyPercentage(percentage = 100)
```

Comment: the script creates the animation keys but I don't know how to select the new keys, either the key before or after the current frame in the timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `selectKey()` it work similiar to the `setKeyframe()` function.

```
key1 = mc.currentTime(q = True)
mc.selectKey(t=(key1-1, key1+1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution to the problem!

Comment: What if I want to select based on percentage, for example select key 2 and key 3 which can be separated by several frames and not only separated in distance by a few frames?